# I want to connect my iMac audio port to both a set of headphones with a mic and a set of external speakers

Tags: audio, splitter, amplification, 3.5mm

I have a 2013 iMac with a 3.5mm headphone jack that provides stereo out and mic input in, I would like to connect this single port to my headphones that have an inline mic so I can listen to music/take phone calls/skype through my computer, or output from the comuter to the speakers for when I want to watch a movie or broadcast music around my apartment. I think I need an audio splitter/amplifier, but I am not sure how they handle input from a mic coming back through one of the outputs. It seems like there should be a simple solution but I cannot find one. Just a quick recap(because sometimes I am not clear) I have 1 3.5mm jack on my iMac (that supplies stereo out and mic in) and 2 3.5mm connections, 1 is a simple stereo connection(the external speakers) and the other is stereo + mic on a single 3.5mm connector(like iphone headphones, I don't know that this is called, and I know sometimes the audio and mic are split into 2 different connectors, but mine isn't). I don't necessarily need the mic to be connected to the speakers, and I don't plan to use both the speakers and headset at the same time. I am looking for cheap recommendations or better search terms to use when looking, or specific places/websites to look.

Comment: walloftext TL:DR

Answer (score 0):

I know one thing you could do is use a splitter.  They should be quite cheap(I got 2 for a dollar).  Connect the headphone to one end and speakers to the other. If you have headphones with dedicated mic port (like mine) then use a splitter for the headphones and connect that to the 2nd splitter . This works for me and hopefully for you too.

Happy listening...

Comment: I have tried that, but it was too quiet, I am hoping to find a splitter with an amplifier to increase the signal